# PHP Check if a user is online

Tags: php, timestamp

Could anyone tell me why this doesn't work?  In my database `lastactive` is `2013-12-10 16:15:12`, updates every time a user refreshes any page on my website.

I select it and set it as a variable:

```
$lastactive = $row[5];
```

Here's where I thought it should work, but doesn't. Using 10 seconds for testing.

```
if(time() > $lastactive+10){
    print('<div id="user_online_status" style="color: #aaa;">[OFFLINE]</div>');
}
else if(time() < $lastactive+10){
    print('<div id="user_online_status">[ONLINE]</div>');
}
```

Comment: You're selecting out a time **STRING**, meaning you're testing `if(123456 > '2013-12-10 hh:mm:ss')`... look at that for a while and try to figure out why it'd never work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your *SELECT* statement from:

```
SELECT lastOnline FROM user
```

to something like...

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastOnline) FROM user
```

that's it. You're currently checking the Date string against a UNIX Timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing a unix timestamp to a MySQL datetime string. You need to convert it to a unix timestamp before comparing the two:

```
$lastactive = strtotime($row[5]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont see its good idea to check for time.

What if user doesnt refresh the page , he let the page open and went to eat ? . he will be loggedout? it will be anonying.

I guess better is to use unload

```
   $(window).unload(function() {
      // Send an Ajax request to logout.php
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

if user doesnt refresh the page, you can check it on server using cron.

```
$limit = $userOnline+60; // cron set to run every minute

if($userOnline < $limit)
  $userStatus = "offline";
else
  $userStatus = "online";
```